# How to terminate specific python program?

Tags: python

So I have two python programs:

```
main.py
sub.py
```

Main contains import `sub.py`, and `sub.py` contains `os._exit(0)`. Problem is that I don't want to close both programs, only `sub.py`.
Is this possible?

Comment: os._exit(0) terminates the main process, so...dont use that...or fork the process in `main.py` before launching `sub.py`

Comment: You are starting one process as `python main.py` and if you import `sub.py` it becomes part of that process. It is not a program on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer: use `return` instead `os._exit(0)`.

Usually using `os._exit(0)` is a bad idea, if you have to - do it from `__main__` in sub.py only. If you don't have other option, you can start sub.py as a new process from main.py with python `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "two python programs", you have two python modules, one of them used as the "main" script (the one your actually execute) and importing the other. At runtime you only have one process, and `os._exit()` kills this process, period.

The fix is very obviously to not use `os._exit()` at all.